# Method not overriding correctly

Tags: java

```
public void run(){
    //This method has a lot of code but it calls the method tick 60 times a second and
    //a method called render as many times as it can
    //Other methods are involved to call this but I took them out because there is not problem with them
}

public void tick(){

    tickB();
    //Other code I don't want to get overwritten 
}

public void render(){

    renderB();
    //Other code I don't want to get overwritten 
}

public void tickB(){System.err.println("Not overwriting");}
public void renderB(){System.err.println("Not overwriting");}
```

While if I run that code I get the error message as I expected, but when I add this project to another project, and extend MainResources (this class) It will not work.

Other project

```
public class Main extends MainResources{

    public void tickB(){
        System.out.println("It worked!");
    }

    public void renderB(){
        System.out.println("It worked!");
    }
}
```

My problem is I don't get the "It worked!", and all code I add gets ignored. I tried adding @Override, but that also does not work. Also I have checked and everything is running correctly to my knowledge.

Comment: It's println, not writeln, for your `System.err`.  It's the same thing as `System.out`; it's just going to a different stream.

Comment: You'll need to reduce it to a [minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Barring the typo (`renerB` instead of `renderB`), the above should work.

Comment: Are you sure that when you compiled your test, you didn't have compilation issues? And so when you ran it, you were running the old class files rather than the new ones?

Comment: I have got no compilation issues with or without the @Override.

Comment: The overriding doesn't help if you're still creating an instance of `MainResources` instead of `Main`.

Comment: How are you invoking the Main class? Please can you as code which shows that?

Comment: Still no MCVE, voting to close.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **only time** you're going to get the overridden message is if you're directly calling `tickB` or `renderB`.  Every other time, you're calling methods on the super class instead.

As it stands, your overridden methods are working as expected.

The important (and interesting) thing here to note is that `System.err` isn't the same as `System.out`, and that writing to one is independent of writing to the other.

So, if you write this...

```
new MainResources().render();
new Main().render();
new Main().tickB();
new Main().renderB();
```

...but see *this* instead...

```
It worked!
It worked!
It worked!
Not overwriting
```

That's just the nature of writing to two output streams.  (It's actually the `MainResources` piece that's got the problem.)